# Unification engine not working on laravel

Tags: laravel, unification, unificationengine

When I am using unification keys for sharing on laravel framework then I am getting  this error

status: 403 and info: forbidden in response.

Thanks

Comment: I have also implemented unification engine in some application this problem is related with parametes

Comment: thanks its working fine as per params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this git code for more details 
https://github.com/unifiedinbox/ue-php-sdk

The optional params for each connections are specified in documentation under 'Add connection' section 
 https://developer.unificationengine.com/

Please let me know if u r facing problem after passing params as per document